# python autoclicker - random time interval

Tags: python, click, pywin32

I have this autoclicker and it works so far.

Most autoclickers have a set time, click every second, every 2 seconds, etc.

I need this program to generate a random time (preferably between .75 and 1.25 seconds).

Anyone have any ideas as to how I could do this?

So my goal is to create an autoclicker that clicks in random time intervals instead of after a set amount of time.

Below is the code I have so far.

```
import win32api, win32con
import time

def click(x,y):

    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,x,y,0,0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,x,y,0,0)

x = 0

while (x < 5):
    a, b = win32api.GetCursorPos()
    click(a, b)
    x = x + 1
```

Comment: How would you do it if you wanted a constant time between clicks?

Comment: @will In the while loop I would put "time.sleep(1)" for one second, etc.

Comment: If you already knew this, it is a very small jump to get to Loquacious' answer then...

Comment: I was trying to grab a start time and end time and go from there, it wasn't working out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `while` loop add the line `time.sleep(0.75 + 0.5*random.random())`.

And add `import random` at the top.